# IIS take long time to first run

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a big website and we converted it to a web application. then again we published the application and get the result files in to another web application and do our own development on top of that. above steps are taken to reduce the build time. it reduced the build time but take long time to the first run. our site containing large number of files. is there any suggessions to reduce the run time. after each and every change we have to wait 5-10 minutes to load the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Application Initialization Module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization) will be usefull for you ;)

**EDIT**

---

Adding following code solved the problem,

```
<compilation optimizeCompilations="true" />
```

> Optional Boolean attribute Specifies whether dynamic compilation will
>   recompile an entire site if a top-level file is changed. Top-level
>   files include the Global.asax file and all files in the Bin and
>   App_Code folders. If True, only changed files are recompiled.The
>   default is False. For more information, see [Understanding ASP.NET
>   Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms366723%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Already installed it but nothing visible after installation. In the IIS manager nothing added for this.

Comment: Then what do you think about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612976/when-my-large-asp-net-site-is-updated-iis-has-to-recompile-a-lot-of-it-is-ther

Comment: `<compilation optimizeCompilations="true" />` solved the problem.